# How do i use a get method to have an edit mode in my user cp

Tags: php

So i have a get method to retrieve info from the url like so

```
$editmode = $_GET['edit'];
```

This is where i am having the issues with proper redirects based on variations of these urls

.../usercp.php --> keeps redirecting me then my browser says theres a redirect problem

.../usercp.php?edit= --> does the same as mentioned above

```
if(!isset($editmode)){
    header('Location: home.php');
}elseif($editmode != 1){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
   //Page Content
}
```

the code is in usercp.php

Comment: Try adding slash `/` before the `usercp.php`. By the way, in what file the codes are in ?

Comment: What system are you using? The system may not allow redirections without a proper sessions. Also a slash may help, or a full URI.

Comment: The code is in the usercp.php file and i have tried the slashes. Im using wamp at the moment but this is going to go on a webserver when im done.

Comment: You are redirecting from `usercp.php` to `usercp.php`? That loop will not come to an end.

Comment: before i posted i did try other pages but then i could not get back to the usercp.

Comment: Your browser produced any error code or description ?

Comment: Then try `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: I'm still suspecting a loop or wrong header location @WASasquatch. Ah, I don't know, too sleepy to think.

Comment: Baha! It may be, though I have used location headers on the same pages for years for when doing tasks to make sure they were complete before displaying, I just used `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` assuming I may change file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$editmode = $_GET['edit'];
if (isset($editmode)===false) {
    header('Location: home.php');
}else if ($editmode != 1){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
   //Page Content
}
?>
```

Comment: That's basically the same thing i had.

Comment: Try going to usercp.php?edit=1 and see if that works, your code is saying, if editmode is not set, it will redirect and then if editmode isn't 1 it will redirect so go to usercp.php?edit=1 and see if it works

Comment: I know that usercp.php?edit=1 works. I was trying to prevent usercp.php?edit= from being used to prevent errors.

Comment: Do you have a redirect loop on the home.php page?

Comment: No I do not have a redirect loop on the homepage.

Comment: try adding `ob_start();` to the start of the usercp.php page